# Convert ResponseEntity<Object> with content type text/plain to object.toString()

Tags: java, spring

I have been hunting for hours for how to do this...

I've explored the Converter class but can't seem to find anything.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to convert a ResponseBody of type Object with Object being a custom object and guide me as to how I return its .toString value when the ResponseEntity contentType is set to text/plain.

EG:

```
    @PostMapping("/example")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> example() {
        Example eg = new Example("Hello World");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).body(eg);
    }
```

This will error with

> WARN 2204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class example.Example] with preset Content-Type 'text/plain']

I know this happens because Spring doesn't know how to convert this object to text/plain format and I am aware I could convert the body to be eg.toString(), but the application requires dynamic response types and therefore would be ideal if I could create a converter to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What would the converted text look like?

Comment: Just whatever is in the .toString() method of the object. EG: "Example [hello=" + hello + "]" - hello being a String in the object

Comment: Did you try [`ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter.html)? This converter might not be enabled by default so this might help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

Comment: @Thomas I noticed the `ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter`, it seems to be ideal but states "By default, this converter supports the media type text/plain only" - I haven't disabled it so I presume it doesn't work - I don't know how I would tell it to convert `Example` object to string when media type is `text/plain`

Comment: I'm no expert here but I'd assume the converter should be selected based on the supported and requested (as in "accepted by the client") media type. However, the article I linked doesn't list `ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter` as one of those that are enabled by default, so you might actually have to enable it (the article should deal with that as well).

Comment: Note that "By default, this converter supports the media type text/plain only." doesn't mean the converter would be enabled by default. It just means that the basic configuration only supports text/plain but the next sentence says: "This can be _overridden_ through the supportedMediaTypes property."

Comment: @Thomas Good point - I've been trying to enable this for the past 20 mins but I can't find anything anywhere... I tried adding a beans.xml file and imported using the `@ImportResource` annotation but no luck

Comment: @Thomas nope must not work - added code `@Configuration
public class Config {
 
 @Bean
 public ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter objectToStringHttpMessageConverter(ConversionService conversionService) {
  System.out.println("adding bean");
  return new ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter(conversionService);
 }

}` The sysout prints, and this should add the bean through the code rather than using a bean config xml but this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the `ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter` class I noticed I wasn't getting an error when letting the object return a response - it was returning "1" with content type as text/plain.

I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter.html) provided by Thomas in the comments above (many thanks). I noticed it stated that this class is a "HttpMessageConverter that uses StringHttpMessageConverter for reading and writing content and a ConversionService for converting the String content to and from the target object type".

After failing to get this class to work I decided to try and create my own implementation of `HttpMessageConverter`. This worked, see below:

```
public class Converter implements HttpMessageConverter<Object> {

@Override
public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
}

@Override
public Response read(Class<? extends Object> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void write(Object t, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    outputMessage.getBody().write(t.toString().getBytes());
}
```

}

- canRead = return false (don't care about parsing strings to their
  corresponding object)
- canWrite = true (you could make this more    fail-safe by adding
  conditions that make it return false if x class    isn't supported or
  a certain media type isn't supported)
- getSupportedMediaTypes - I want this converter to convert objects to
  plain text
- read = don't care about reading
- write = write the object       .toString() method to the
  outputMessage OutputStream

Then, you just need to add this converter to the converter list in a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new Converter());
    }

}
```